# Horizontal BarChart with labels and additional text

Tags: chart.js, bar-chart, axis-labels

I would like to create a horizontal BarChart.
The data range is from 0 to 20 or from 0 to -20.
The labels of the data should always be on the opposite side of the bar.
I also need additional text on the left and right.

The picture should make it clear:
[image]
I would like to do it with Chart.js.

### edit:

This is my approach with Chart.js:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var chartStatus = Chart.getChart("myChart");
if (chartStatus != undefined) {
  chartStatus.destroy();
}
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "bar",

  data: {
    labels: ["Cats", "Dogs", "Dugs", "Mice", "Hamster", "Tiger"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: false,
        data: [-9, 1, 9, -9, 1, 9],
        // data: [12, 19, -3],
        backgroundColor: [
          "rgba(39, 152, 228, 0.7)",
          "rgba(233, 85, 59, 0.7)",
          "rgba(152, 140, 202, 0.7)",
          "rgba(39, 152, 228, 0.7)",
          "rgba(233, 85, 59, 0.7)",
          "rgba(152, 140, 202, 0.7)"
        ],
        borderColor: [
          "rgba(39, 152, 228,1)",
          "rgba(233, 85, 59, 1)",
          "rgba(152, 140, 202, 1)",
          "rgba(39, 152, 228,1)",
          "rgba(233, 85, 59, 1)",
          "rgba(152, 140, 202, 1)"
        ],
        borderWidth: 6
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    indexAxis: "y",
    plugins: {
      gridLines: {
        display: false
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: "Pets",
        font: {
          size: 22
        }
      },
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      tooltip: {
        enabled: false
      }
    },

    scales: {
      x: {
        min: -20,
        max: 20,
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          color: "#d6d6d9",
          font: {
            size: 22
          }
        }
      },
      y: {
        labels: ["Text1", "Text2", "Text3", "Text4", "Text5", "Text6"],
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        barPercentage: 1,
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          color: "#d6d6d9",
          font: {
            size: 22
          }
        }
      },
      gridLines: {
        display: false
      },
      secondY: {
        labels: ["Text7", "Text8", "Text9", "Text10", "Text11", "Text12"],
        position: "right",

        ticks: {
          color: "#d6d6d9",
          font: {
            size: 22
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.min.js" integrity="sha512-QSkVNOCYLtj73J4hbmVoOV6KVZuMluZlioC+trLpewV8qMjsWqlIQvkn1KGX2StWvPMdWGBqim1xlC8krl1EKQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<img style="display:none" id="url" />
```

I could solve the different text for the left and the right side with the `labels` on the respective axes.

But how do I get the labels (cat, dog etc) into the graph so that they are always on the opposite side of the bars?

Comment: please dont reply, got a good hint: https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/issues/605 will post the solution

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var chartStatus = Chart.getChart("myChart");
if (chartStatus != undefined) {
  chartStatus.destroy();
}
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "bar",

  data: {
    labels: ["Cats", "Dogs", "Dugs", "Mice", "Hamster", "Tiger"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: false,
        data: [-9, 1, 9, -9, 1, 9],
        // data: [12, 19, -3],
        backgroundColor: [
          "rgba(39, 152, 228, 0.7)",
          "rgba(233, 85, 59, 0.7)",
          "rgba(152, 140, 202, 0.7)",
          "rgba(39, 152, 228, 0.7)",
          "rgba(233, 85, 59, 0.7)",
          "rgba(152, 140, 202, 0.7)"
        ],
        borderColor: [
          "rgba(39, 152, 228,1)",
          "rgba(233, 85, 59, 1)",
          "rgba(152, 140, 202, 1)",
          "rgba(39, 152, 228,1)",
          "rgba(233, 85, 59, 1)",
          "rgba(152, 140, 202, 1)"
        ],
        borderWidth: 6
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    animation: {
      duration: 1,
      // https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/issues/605
      onComplete: function () {
        var chart = this;
        var ctx = chart.ctx;

        ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(
          Chart.defaults.font.size,
          Chart.defaults.font.style,
          Chart.defaults.font.family
        );
        ctx.textAlign = "left";
        ctx.textBaseline = "censter";
        var labels = this.data.labels;
        this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
          var meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(i);
          meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
            var data = dataset.data[index];
            let posx;
            if (data < 0) {
              posx = bar.x + bar.$context.element.width + 10;
              ctx.textAlign = "left";
            } else {
              posx = bar.x - bar.$context.element.width - 10;
              ctx.textAlign = "right";
            }
            // posx = bar.x;
            ctx.fillText(`${labels[index]} (${data})`, posx, bar.y + 3);
          });
        });
 
      }
    },
    responsive: true,
    indexAxis: "y",
    plugins: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: "Pets",
        font: {
          size: 22
        }
      },
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      tooltip: {
        enabled: false
      }
    },

    scales: {
      x: {
        grid: {
          display: false,
          drawBorder: false,
          drawOnChartArea: false,
          drawTicks: false
        },
        labels: {
          display: false
        },
        min: -20,
        max: 20,
        ticks: {
          color: "#d6d6d9",
          font: {
            size: 22
          }
        }
      },
      y: {
        grid: {
          display: false,
          drawBorder: false,
          drawOnChartArea: false,
          drawTicks: false
        },
        labels: ["Text1", "Text2", "Text3", "Text4", "Text5", "Text6"],
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        barPercentage: 1,

        ticks: {
          color: "#d6d6d9",
          font: {
            size: 22
          }
        }
      },
      secondY: {
        labels: ["Text7", "Text8", "Text9", "Text10", "Text11", "Text12"],
        position: "right",
        grid: {
          display: false,
          drawBorder: false,
          drawOnChartArea: false,
          drawTicks: false
        },
        ticks: {
          color: "#d6d6d9",
          font: {
            size: 22
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.min.js" integrity="sha512-QSkVNOCYLtj73J4hbmVoOV6KVZuMluZlioC+trLpewV8qMjsWqlIQvkn1KGX2StWvPMdWGBqim1xlC8krl1EKQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```